# How to dispose/release/"finalize" unmanaged resources when a shared value gets out of scope

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, dispose, ghc, finalizer

I have a type that encapsulates a key to an external resource. Once the key is lost (all values that share it get out of scope), the resource should be released (implicitly) on the next garbage-collection, like memory does for regular values.

So I'm looking for something similar to OOP disposing, or [`ForeignPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html), only that I represent references to something other than objects from foreign languages (although if [`ForeignPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html) can properly and elegantly work for this too, knowing how would also answer this question).

Is it possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`System.Mem.Weak.addFinalizer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-Mem-Weak.html#v:addFinalizer) for this.

Unfortunately the semantics for weak references can be a little difficult to understand at first.  The warning note is particularly important.

If you can attach an [`IORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-IORef.html), [`MVar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html), or [`TVar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.4.3/docs/Control-Concurrent-STM-TVar.html) to your key, and make a weak reference/finalizer associated with that, it's likely to be much more reliable.

In the special case that your key is a pointer to non-managed memory (e.g. some C data structure), you should instead create a [`ForeignPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html) and attach a finalizer to it.  The semantics for these finalizers are a little different; rather than an arbitrary IO action the finalizer must be a function pointer to an external function.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you look at [ResourceT](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/resourcet):

> ResourceT is a monad transformer which creates a region of code where
>   you can safely allocate resources.